# How to select and play multiple songs in a list?

Tags: wpf, listbox, mediaelement

I have a requirement, I need to play multiple audio songs on window using wpf.Can anyone suggest the best way to implement this.

I have window. There I will display the list of the songs in list box. User should able to select the multiple songs from the list box and click play.

I have to play the all audio songs selected by user one by one.

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to have a ListBox control with its ItemsSource property bound to some collection ("SongList" for example).

```
<ListBox Name="lstSongs" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SongList}" SelectionMode="Extended" Grid.Row="1" />
```

Have a MediaElement control on the page listening for the next song

```
<MediaElement Name="player" MediaEnded="MediaElement_MediaEnded" LoadedBehavior="Play" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" Source="{Binding Path=CurrentlyPlaying}" />
```

When the user clicks a button on the form, the currently selected items are added to a queue. The currently selected items can be found by reading the ListBox.SelectedItems property.

```
private void cmdQueueItems_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Queue = lstSongs.SelectedItems.OfType<Uri>().ToList();
    playNext();
}
```

You then start playing the first item in the queue, and when the `MediaElement.MediaEnded` event is raised, replace the currently playing item with the next item in the queue if there is one available.

```
private void MediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    playNext();
}
```

You would do this until the user hit a predefined stop button.

The `playNext()` method would just simply be

```
private void playNext()
{
    CurrentlyPlaying = Queue.FirstOrDefault();

    if (CurrentlyPlaying != null)
        Queue.Remove(CurrentlyPlaying);
}
```

(Make sure that the CurrentlyPlaying property raises the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event)

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public List<Uri> Queue { get; private set; }

    #region CurrentlyPlaying Definition

    private Uri _CurrentlyPlaying = null;

    public Uri CurrentlyPlaying
    {
        get
        {
            return _CurrentlyPlaying;
        }
        set
        {
            _CurrentlyPlaying = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentlyPlaying");
        }
    }

    #endregion // end of CurrentlyPlaying region

    public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Uri> SongList { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        SongList = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Uri>();

        SongList.Add(new Uri(@"E:\Music\_relaxation\African Drums - Tribal Music.mp3"));
        SongList.Add(new Uri(@"E:\Music\Disturbed\Disturbed - A Welcme Burden.mp3"));
    }

    private void cmdQueueItems_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Queue = lstSongs.SelectedItems.OfType<Uri>().ToList();
        playNext();
    }

    private void cmdSkipItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        playNext();
    }

    private void MediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        playNext();
    }

    private void playNext()
    {
        CurrentlyPlaying = Queue.FirstOrDefault();

        if (CurrentlyPlaying != null)
            Queue.Remove(CurrentlyPlaying);
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <MediaElement Name="player" MediaEnded="MediaElement_MediaEnded" LoadedBehavior="Play" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" Source="{Binding Path=CurrentlyPlaying}" />
    <ListBox Name="lstSongs" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SongList}" SelectionMode="Extended" Grid.Row="1" />
    <Button Content="Play selected" Click="cmdQueueItems_Click" Grid.Row="2" />
    <Button Content="Skip" Click="cmdSkipItem_Click" Grid.Row="3" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: i have selected 2 songs from the list box and i added to the queue then i clicked on play button...but it is not playing...what should i do?

Comment: Have you set up your bindings correctly? Are the Uri's valid? I have updated my post with full source.

Comment: Have you copied my code *exactly*? Namely the `LoadedBehavior` and `UnloadedBehavior` properties? If so, does it work in a stand-alone application, or are you trying to add it to your application? When the `playNext()` method executes, does the `CurrentlyPlaying` property change? If so, is the PropertyChanged event being fired?